# How to extract frame timing information from animated GIF?

Tags: .net, animation, standards, animated-gif

This is brought on by a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796186/animated-gif-in-imagelist-tabpage). Apparently `ImageList` doesn't support animated GIFs, so I'm stuck animating it myself.

I know [how to extract the frames](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif.html), but does anyone know how to extract the *frame timing information* from an animated GIF?

Comment: What the heck is going on here? I keep getting downvoted on this question recently and nobody wants to comment why? Did something change in .net in the past three years that someone wants to *answer this question with and explain*?

Comment: fwiw, I found the question/answer helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the duration of the current frame (having called `SelectActiveFrame`), using a call to [`Image.GetPropertyItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getpropertyitem.aspx), as such:

```
var duration = image.GetPropertyItem(0x5100).Value;
```

I believe the duration value is measured in 1/100ths of seconds.

Comment: Excellent. Now that I look a little harder (specifically for image propertyitem), I find a list at http://www.bobpowell.net/discoverproperties.htm but I was *not* going to find this one easily. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Also, that's a good resource you've found there; I would have linked you to a list of all the property codes for animated GIFs, but I couldn't find one at the time.